# Bytestring containing '*', '+', ')', '@', among other unusual characters

Tags: python

As part of a longer project, I've experimented with audio encoding and decoding with python, using the pyaudio and wave libraries.

I've begun by creating a subroutine that reads data from a wave file, and each time it reads a frame of data from the wave file, it writes it to a text file by converting the bytestring it receives from the wave file to a string it can write to a text file.

That's all fine, but I'm very confused by some of the characters appearing, and I was wondering if there were any explanations to what some of these characters actually mean/do within the context of bytestrings, or if they are erroneous and my program is faulty:

- `b'*\x0f+\x0f'` (I was not expecting `*` or `+`)
- `b'+\x03)\x03'` (I was not expecting `+` or `)`)
- `b'@\xf2D\xf2'` (I was not expecting `@` or `D`)

There are several other odd combinations, but is there any explanations to these characters that would in turn make my understanding of the other unusual characters clearer? I'm quite new to understanding bytestrings, so please keep that in mind.

Comment: This is audio data, right? It's binary, not text. Those are just bytes that happen to  represent printable ASCII characters when interpreted as text.

Comment: E.g., `b'\x2a' == b'*'` evaluates to `True`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I am well aware that it is binary from audio data - what my confusion is about is the role of these odd characters in the bytestring. The usual pattern, as I have observed, is ```\x00\x00\x00\x00``` for one frame of 32-bit data, is it not?

Comment: Use `binascii.hexlify()` to get a pure-hexadecimal view of your data, even for the 95 out of 256 possible byte values that fall within the printable ASCII range.

Comment: How exactly are you converting the data? The strings you posted look as if nothing was converted - you just treat the wave data as if it was already text, and let python "do its thing" by printing out hex values for bytes that do not correspond to printable characters.

Comment: @LevM. Sorry, I didn't mean converting, I mean transferring from an audio wave file comprising pure binary to a text file comprising text.

Comment: @RWN then you should note that if you write these strings to a file as they are, you will not get a text file, but just a copy of the wave file. The conversion to '\x' is only done by pythons print function, if you use file class `write` function it will write the bytes to file as is.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "text-file" as such, there's just "files" which all contain streams of bytes. By convention, we call a file a "text file" if it contains only bytes which can be interpreted as text. So if you write binary (wave) data to a file, it will be a wave file, not a text file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When possible, a byte in a `byte` value is displayed as the ASCII character encoded by the byte.

```
>>> ord('*')
42
>>> b'\x2a'  # 0x2a == 42
b'*'
```

Otherwise, the `\xXX` format is used.

```
>>> b'\x00\x2a'  # Two bytes: the null byte and 42
b'\x00*'
```

Comment: So these random characters correspond to a specific combination of two hexadecimal digits, i.e., ```b'x2a'``` = ```b'*'```, like a dictionary key/value?

Comment: I guess you could put it that way, yes. `\x..` is only used when that byte doesn't correspond to a printable ASCII character.